# Rollback transactions made by two different DBContext saves when an exception occurs

Tags: entity-framework

I need to save to two different databases after some user action. Currently, I have the following:

```
using (EFEntities1 dc = new EFEntities1())
{
     dc.USERS.Add(user);
     dc.SaveChanges();
}

using (EFEntities2 dc = new EFEntities2())
{
     dc.USERS.Add(user);
     dc.SaveChanges();
}
```

These are two separate code blocks within the same method, so I believe if the second one fails, the first one won't rollback. How do I make sure both transactions rollback if something fails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap them in a [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx).  Note that this will probably call the [DTC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684146%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())  
{
  using (EFEntities1 dc = new EFEntities1())
  {
     dc.USERS.Add(user);
     dc.SaveChanges();
  }

  using (EFEntities2 dc = new EFEntities2())
  {
     dc.USERS.Add(user);
     dc.SaveChanges();
  }

  scope.complete();
}
```

Comment: If I rollout the application to users, do they need to turn on MSDTC on their machine or does this need to be done once on the server?

Comment: If you need the DTC, you're going to have to put it on both the machines and the servers. However, you may, or may not need it - depending on what exactly you're doing, and the SQL server version...

Comment: So if I use one TransactionScope for connection to two different databases, then I need the DTC? I'm using SQL Azure.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with SQL Azure - my best advice is try it, and see if you need it decides to elevate